# rest-client: How to limit rest request to ask only for the first 5 records?

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I am new to Ruby, and to rest-client.
I would like to fetch the first 5 articles from the following endpoint.
How can I adjust my request so the endpoint will fetch only 5 records?

```
require 'rest-client'

resposnse = RestClient.get 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json'
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Is there a documentation of the API available?

Comment: This depends on the API supporting this, which [based on the documentation](https://github.com/HackerNews/API) it doesn't seem to do.  Instead you can just take the top 5 results from the response.

Comment: You can try walking backwards from maxitem: https://github.com/HackerNews/API#max-item-id